# How does Kotlin know that applicationContext comes from getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development and Kotlin.  I'm currently learning Java for Android, but the [Hilt tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-hilt/#0) is in Kotlin, so I need to learn the bare minimum of Kotlin to get through these tutorials.

The code I'm curious about is this:

```
01 @AndroidEntryPoint
02 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
03
04     private lateinit var navigator: AppNavigator
05
06     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
07         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
08         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
09
10         navigator = (applicationContext as LogApplication).serviceLocator.provideNavigator(this)
11
12         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
13             navigator.navigateTo(Screens.BUTTONS)
14         }
15     }
16
17     override fun onBackPressed() {
18         super.onBackPressed()
19
20         if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
21             finish()
22         }
23     }
24 }
```

I'm in Android Studio.  When I put my cursor on the `applicationContext` variable on line 10 and hit F12, it goes to this:

```
public class ContextWrapper extends Context {
    ...

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return mBase.getApplicationContext();
    }

    ...
}
```

There is no field called `applicationContext`.  How does Kotlin link those two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of Kotlin – Java interoperability. From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with `get` and single-argument methods with names starting with `set`) are represented as properties in Kotlin. Boolean accessor methods (where the name of the getter starts with is and the name of the setter starts with set) are represented as properties which have the same name as the getter method.